# VLOOKUP returns a Empty value even when value is present in the table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to perform Vlookup on my table

I declared the 3 variables as variants so there aren't any type mismatch errors.

```
Dim resultA As Variant
Dim resultB As Variant
Dim resultC As Variant
```

```
resultA = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnA.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)
resultB = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnB.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)
resultC = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnC.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)
```

The error is coming in **resultC**, the debugger shows that it's "empty" and resultA and resultB as error 2042.

When I comment out result C, the code is working as expected (Result A and Result B are able to store the correct values)

Below is an example of the data I am using

| ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test data | Sample text | $ 1000.89 |
| 2 | Test data 1 | Sample Text | $ 1000.67 |

I tried declaring the variables as variant type which did not work.

When I changed the values in the table to just small numbers (30,40,50), the code was working but it isn't for these accounting type numbers ($5000.89)

Below is the complete code which you can use to recreate the error.

```
    Sub AbraKadabra()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mainColA As Range
    Dim mainColB As Range
    Dim mainColC As Range
    Dim dataLastRow As Long
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Dim idColumn As Range
    Dim resultColumnA As Range
    Dim resultColumnB As Range
    Dim resultColumnC As Range
    Dim colNum1 As Integer
    Dim colNum2 As Integer
    Dim colNum3 As Integer
    Dim testVar As Variant
    
    ' Set the workbook and main sheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set mainSheet = wb.Worksheets("mainSheet") ' Use main sheet name
    
    ' Find the last row in the main sheet
    lastRow = mainSheet.Cells(mainSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    colNum1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column A", mainSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    colNum2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column B", mainSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    colNum3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column C", mainSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    
    Set mainColA = mainSheet.Columns(colNum1)
    Set mainColB = mainSheet.Columns(colNum2)
    Set mainColC = mainSheet.Columns(colNum3)

    ' Set the ranges for the main sheet columns
    ' Set mainColA = mainSheet.Rows(1).Find("Column A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' Set mainColB = mainSheet.Rows(1).Find("Column B", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' Set mainColC = mainSheet.Rows(1).Find("Column C", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If mainColA Is Nothing Or mainColB Is Nothing Or mainColC Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "One or more column headers not found in the main sheet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

      ' Loop through each row in the main sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the data starts from row 2, change as needed
        ' Get the ID for each row in the main sheet
        Dim id As Variant
        id = mainSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Assuming the ID is in column A, change as needed
        
        ' Loop through each data sheet
        For Each dataSheet In wb.Sheets
            If dataSheet.Name <> mainSheet.Name Then ' Skip the main sheet itself
                ' Find the last row in the data sheet
                dataLastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                
                ' Set the range for the data sheet columns
                Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range("A1:Z" & dataLastRow) ' Adjust the range as needed
                
                ' Set the range for the ID column and the result columns in the data sheet
                Set idColumn = dataRange.Columns(1) ' Assuming the ID column is in column A
                Set resultColumnA = dataRange.Rows(1).Find("Column A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                Set resultColumnB = dataRange.Rows(1).Find("Column B", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                Set resultColumnC = dataRange.Rows(1).Find("Column C", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                
                ' Set the lookup range for VLOOKUP
                ' Set lookupRange = dataRange.Columns(1) ' Assuming the lookup range is the ID column

                ' Use VLOOKUP to find the corresponding values in the data sheet
                Dim resultA As Variant
                Dim resultB As Variant
                Dim resultC As Variant
                resultA = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnA.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)
                resultB = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnB.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)
                resultC = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnC.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)

                
                If Not IsError(resultA) Then
                    ' Populate particular columns in the main sheet with data from the data sheet
                    mainSheet.Cells(i, mainColA.Column).Value = resultA
                    mainSheet.Cells(i, mainColB.Column).Value = resultB
                    mainSheet.Cells(i, mainColC.Column).Value = resultC
                   
                    Exit For ' Exit the loop if a match is found in the current data sheet
                End If
            End If
        Next dataSheet
    Next i
    
    ' Cleanup
    Set mainSheet = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Final Update: Apologies for the confusion, the code was working perfectly fine. The issue was that the type of the header of Column C was of a different type (Should've been "General" but it was of "Accounting" type).

TLDR; Make sure the column headers for your table are of "General" type

Comment: 2042 is the #N/A error which means that your lookup did not find a match.

Comment: So when I comment out column C and I run the vlookup for column A and B there are no errors. I get the values from Column A and Column B as expected.
@Rory But when all 3 run together, I get the error in Column C which somehow cascades to the other values?

I've updated my table to show the ID column, the value I search on is an integer.
The value I store in the variable is a floating point integer that I get from the row where that particular ID is present

Comment: Btw, there's no such thing as a floating-point integer.

Comment: I meant a floating point number, like a double/float data type.

Comment: "I get the error in Column C which somehow cascades to the other values" - please add more detail around exactly how you determined that, because it's difficult to see how it could happen from what you've posted.  A full set of code to replicate the problem would be very useful here.

Comment: Have you tried converting your floating point number variable to an INT?  With some of the precision issues that Excel has, that may resolve the issue.

Comment: That all works fine for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd find something like this easier to maintain.  When performing multiple lookups against the same range, it's faster to do a single `Match()` to get the matched row, and then get the values from that row.  This also allows you to change the number of headers or their values in a single place.

```vb
Sub AbraKadabra()
    Dim wb As Workbook, mainSheet As Worksheet, dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, dataLastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim mainHeaderPos, dataHeaderPos, arrHeaders, id, m
    Dim dataRange As Range
    
    arrHeaders = Array("Column A", "Column B", "Column C") 'column headers to be transferred
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set mainSheet = wb.Worksheets("mainSheet")
    
    mainHeaderPos = GetColumnIndexes(mainSheet.Rows(1), arrHeaders) 'main sheet header indexes
    If IsEmpty(mainHeaderPos) Then Exit Sub  'exit if any headers we not found on main sheet
    
    For i = 2 To mainSheet.Cells(mainSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
        id = mainSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Assuming the ID is in column A, change as needed
        
        For Each dataSheet In wb.Sheets ' Loop through each data sheet
            If dataSheet.Name <> mainSheet.Name Then ' Skip the main sheet itself
                
                dataLastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
                Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range("A1:Z" & dataLastRow)
                
                dataHeaderPos = GetColumnIndexes(dataRange.Rows(1), arrHeaders) 'find the column headers
                If IsEmpty(dataHeaderPos) Then Exit Sub 'optional: exit if all headers not found...
                
                m = Application.Match(id, dataRange.Columns(1), 0)
                If Not IsError(m) Then 'got an id match ?
                    For n = LBound(mainHeaderPos) To UBound(mainHeaderPos) 'loop headers
                        mainSheet.Cells(i, mainHeaderPos(n)).Value = _
                           dataRange.Cells(m, dataHeaderPos(n)).Value
                    Next n
                    Exit For 'stop checking other sheets
                End If
            End If
        Next dataSheet
    Next i
    
End Sub

'get the indexes of column headers in `ArrHeaders` looking at row `rw`
'  and return as an array
Function GetColumnIndexes(rw As Range, arrHeaders As Variant) As Variant
    Dim m, rv, i As Long
    ReDim rv(LBound(arrHeaders) To UBound(arrHeaders))
    For i = LBound(arrHeaders) To UBound(arrHeaders)
        m = Application.Match(arrHeaders(i), rw, 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            rv(i) = m  'record the header position
        Else
            'warn if missing, and return Empty
            MsgBox "Column header '" & arrHeaders(i) & _
                   "' not found on sheet '" & rw.Parent.Name & "'"
            GetColumnIndexes = Empty
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    GetColumnIndexes = rv 'all good if got here
End Function
```

Comment: You really only need to call `GetColumnIndexes()` on the sheet that has an id match

Comment: ...or only try looking up a value if the required headers are present?  Either way, this is not super-efficient and there's likely a better way to structure it.